# Creating a ticketing system in Drupal 8. How to change a node's field value without going to the edit page?

Tags: 8, entities, ajax

I'm creating a simple ticketing system in Drupal 8 to log my daily tasks. The content type contains title, body, and ticket status. The status field can be new, in progress, or completed. When I create a new ticket, the status is set as new by default. I also have commenting enabled on this content type.

The issue I'm having now is the UX of this setup. I can comment on the ticket fine, but if I were to change the **status** of the ticket to **in progress** or **completed**, I'd have to goto the edit page of the node and make this change. How can I change the status value without going to the edit page? Is there a ajax field update feature?

I wan't to be able to make my comment and also change the status of the ticket all at once vs making a comment, then click edit to change the status.

Answer (score 2):

You could build an ajax form that would update the node's "Ticket Status" field, embed that in a custom block and place that block on the page for that node or embed it in the node.  Instead of in a block, you could also create a field formatter plugin that embeds the ajax form into the display for that field.

Comment: any example code I can follow to get this done? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There a thousands of ways you can place a minified node edit form, see your last question [Creating a ticket system with core only. How to modify fields on full_content view without reloading?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/226846/creating-a-ticket-system-with-core-only-how-to-modify-fields-on-full-content-vi) or the great answer from @oknate [Creating a ticketing system in Drupal 8. How to change a node's field value without going to the edit page?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/237080/creating-a-ticketing-system-in-drupal-8-how-to-change-a-nodes-field-value-with/237089#237089)

But what is new in this question is, that you want to do this together with the comment form. The comment form has already a submit that posts data to drupal. Then you don't need a second form. You could extend the comment form in a form alter hook with two submit buttons, which each execute not only the default submit from the comment form, but also a custom submit which changes the status of the parent node either to **progress** or **completed**.